# postgres json_b array does not contain partial object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

given a json_b array column named `attributes` that contains multiple json objects. how can i query the `attributes` column to get all those rows which does not have a specific value in any json object in the column.

for instance, given the following 4 rows

```json
[{"one": 1}, {"two":2}, {"three": 3, "foo": "foo", "baz": "baz"}]
[{"one": 1}, {"three": 3, "foo": "foo" }]
[{"foo": "foo" }]
[{"one": 1}, {"two":2}, {"three": 3, "baz": "baz"}]
```

i would like to get all those rows that does not have `"foo": "foo"` in any object in the array. in the example above, the last row should return.

the array could be converted to text and then use `like` operator for matching string, but this is error prone and might run longer due to the conversion to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS function to unnest the JSON objects within the "attributes" array column and then filter. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    attributes JSONB
);

--Sample data
INSERT INTO my_table (attributes) VALUES
('[{"one": 1}, {"two":2}, {"three": 3, "foo": "foo", "baz": "baz"}]'),
('[{"one": 1}, {"three": 3, "foo": "foo" }]'),
('[{"foo": "foo" }]'),
('[{"one": 1}, {"two":2}, {"three": 3, "baz": "baz"}]');

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(attributes) AS elem
  WHERE elem->>'foo' = 'foo'
);
```

I have added dummy data into the table and tried the query and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the `jsonb_path_exists` function along with an expression:

```
FROM your_table
WHERE NOT jsonb_path_exists(
    your_column,
    '$[*] ? (@.foo == "foo")'
);
```